# How do I get regular paragraph movement in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Org mode overrides paragraph movement to replace `forward-paragraph` with `org-forward-paragraph`. How do I access the normal `forward-paragraph` command?

I'm happy to rebind the `org-forward-paragraph` if I have to change code somewhere. I just want to have access to both functions. `org-forward-paragraph` is great, but sometimes I want `forward-paragraph` in an org document.

Even if you call `M-x forward-paragraph`, `org-forward-paragraph` is executed. I want to be able to bind `forward paragraph`. I have a logging package that shows that `org-forward-paragraph` is being called for these below bindings (instead of the bound `forward-paragraph`).

I've tried this:

```
(bind-key "<f5> 3" 'forward-paragraph org-mode-map)
```

and this:

```
(defun my-org-forward-paragraph-override ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-paragraph))
(bind-key "<f5> 3" 'my-org-forward-paragraph-override org-mode-map)
```

With the following org doc, and the cursor at the beginning, I expect `M-x forward-paragraph` to move to the first empty line (the end of the first paragraph). Instead, it moves to the end of the file and tells me to call `forward-paragraph` with `C-<down>` (which calls `org-forward-paragraph`).

```
* heading 1
* heading 2

* heading 3
```

The issue can be replicated in `emacs -q` by creating the above org doc, switching to `scratch` and executing the below binding; `C-h k C-c 2` then shows that `org-forward-paragraph` is being called instead of the bound `forward-paragraph`

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c 2") #'forward-paragraph)
```

Comment: What would you consider to be adequate access to `forward-paragraph` in an org document? Are you looking for something more than `M-x forward-paragraph`?

Comment: The question could be clearer. Are you just asking how to bind `forward-paragraph` to a key, in an Org mode keymap?

Comment: Even if you call M-x forward-paragraph, org-forward-paragraph is executed. I want to execute forward-paragraph.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the behaviour you are experiencing. Calling `M-x forward-paragraph` within an org doc works as expected, not as `org-forward-paragraph`. (Checked through messages log, command log, and by seeing how the command treats "org units" like lists and tables.) Have you checked if anything in your config could be causing problems here?

Comment: I can replicate my issue with "emacs -q". I have edited my question to show an explicit example of the behavior I'm talking about. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the intended behavior of forward-paragraph.

Comment: I understand your confusion. org-mode is really confusing about certain special `org-` functions, and doesn't bind them in the conventional way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Tyler's diagnosis](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74271/14825) is correct, but there is no need to define a renamed function just to do this. All you have to do is undo the remapping of `forward-paragraph` that Org mode did. The [remapping section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html) of the manual tells you how to do that:

```el
;;; traditional
(define-key my-mode-map [remap forward-paragraph] nil)
;;; ... or recent Emacsen(?)
(keymap-set org-mode-map "<remap> <forward-paragraph>" nil)
```

You just remap it to `nil`.

The current online manual shows the first version, but the 29.0.50 manual shows the second one: they are equivalent but the second version may not be available if your version of Emacs is older.

The two functions can now independently be bound to keys. Note that `forward-paragraph` is still bound to `C-<down>`, so only the Org variant key binding needs to be defined.

Comment: This is great and makes my config look a little nicer than the other answer (the other answer is fine, though, like you said).

Comment: Credit where credit is due: without @Tyler's answer, this answer would probably not exist.  He pointed out the remapping - since I didn't know anything about it, I followed up in the manual and saw the above mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

`orgmode` defines special 'super' functions that take over many typical Emacs functions, and binds them in a way that makes it difficult to override them. You can look into the details in the function `org-remap`, in the file `org-keys.el`. The main point is, any key you bind to one of these super functions, and `forward-paragraph` is one of them, will actually get bound to the `org` version instead.

If you want to use one of these normal functions, you need to give it a different name to call, so `org`'s remapping won't catch it. In your case, the following worked for me:

```
(defun my-org-forward-paragraph-override ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-paragraph))


(define-key org-mode-map "\M-p" 'my-org-forward-paragraph-override)
```

With this config, `M-p` gives you the regular behaviour of `forward-paragraph`.

By contrast, the following doesn't work:

```
(define-key org-mode-map "\M-o" 'forward-paragraph)
```

With this config, `M-o` calls `org-forward-paragraph`, even though you (thought you) told it to call `forward-paragraph`.

Comment: Thanks. I was on the right trail but got wrapped around the axle with a compounding issue not realizing I bound again later differently. This clarification was what I was looking for.